# Eclipse GIT issue: Unable to checkout branch (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: eclipse, egit, jgit

Git throws exception 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect' when I tried to checkout a existing branch.

**Error log:**

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:294)
at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.BranchOperation$1.run(BranchOperation.java:133)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2326)
at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.BranchOperation.execute(BranchOperation.java:156)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.branch.BranchOperationUI.run(BranchOperationUI.java:258)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.CreateBranchPage.createBranch(CreateBranchPage.java:475)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.CreateBranchWizard$1.run(CreateBranchWizard.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.CreateBranchWizard.performFinish(CreateBranchWizard.java:87)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.branch.BranchOperationUI.getTargetWithDialog(BranchOperationUI.java:276)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.branch.BranchOperationUI.start(BranchOperationUI.java:152)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.SwitchToMenu$1.widgetSelected(SwitchToMenu.java:120)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkoutEntry(DirCacheCheckout.java:968)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.doCheckout(DirCacheCheckout.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkout(DirCacheCheckout.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:240)
    ... 51 more
```

**Cause:**
A trailing white space in folder name.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a cause of this issue. By mistake, A developer put a trailing white space in name of new folder. and pushed this commit.

**Folder name:**

```
'myFolder '
```

When I try to checkout any branch with above commit, 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect' error will occurred. When he has renamed folder name (removed trailing space). and he pushed this commit. Now I am able to checkout this branch.